# I am having trouble with multiple chars and scanf_s()

Tags: c, visual-studio, scanf, unhandled-exception, tr24731

I'm trying to use `scanf_s()` to read in multiple values but every time I run the program, I get

> Unhandled exception at 0x592AD6AC (msvcr120d.dll) in lab 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

in a popup window. How do I fix this?

```
float inTemp;
char inUnit;
char outUnit;

printf("Please enter the starting temperature with its units and the units\nyou would like to convert to (i.e. 74.5 F C): ");
scanf_s("%f %c %c", &inTemp, &inUnit, &outUnit); //takes in all user input (NOT WORKING)
```

Comment: Check the materials about [`scanf_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) again please,

Comment: Consider putting a `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` on top of your source files and using `scanf` instead for a portable code.

Answer (score 4):

You have not provided a length indicator. From MSDN:

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size
>   to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string
>   control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is
>   passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to
>   the buffer or variable. For example, if you are reading a string, the
>   buffer size for that string is passed as follows: char s[10];
>   scanf_s("%9s", s, _countof(s)); // buffer size is 10, width
>   specification is 9

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) is a link to that page.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use (less portable) `scanf_s`, from the C11 standard (n1570), Annex K 3.5.3.2 p.4:

> The `fscanf_s` function is equivalent to `fscanf` except that the `c`, `s`, and `[` conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments (unless assignment suppression is indicated by a `*`). The first of these arguments is the same as for `fscanf`. That argument is immediately followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type `rsize_t` and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by the first argument of the pair.

You need to give the lengths of your `char *` arguments:

```
scanf_s("%f %c %c", &inTemp, &inUnit, 1, &outUnit, 1);
```

Alternatively, just use `scanf`:

```
scanf("%f %c %c", &inTemp, &inUnit, &outUnit);
```

And, as always, check the return values.

In general, as `scanf` is somtimes useful for little quick-and-dirty programmes, it’s of less use for productive software, because handling errors is hard. Use `fgets` and `sscanf`/`strtod`/`strtol`/… instead.